# Jest failed to build dependency graph, collision between source and build files

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs

I'm using babel to transpile files from src to lib and when i try to run jest I get a conflict between `src/Template.js` and `lib/Template.js`

```
Using Jest CLI v0.9.0, jasmine2, babel-jest

Error: Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: Template
Paths: src/Template.js collides with lib/Template.js
```

How should one deal with this scenario? Is there maybe a way to ignore one of the directories?

In package.json:

- babel-cli@6.x
- babel-jest@9.x
- babel-polyfill@6.x
- babel-preset-es2015@6.x
- babel-preset-react@6.x
- jasmine@2.x
- jasmine-spec-reporter@2.x
- jest-cli@0.9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that jest is by default searching the whole project for tests.
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-testpathdirs-array-string

Solution in package.json

```
"jest": {
  "testPathDirs": [
    "<rootDir>/__tests__", # Default is <rootDir>
    "<rootDir>/lib" # Needed for automatic mocking to work
  ],
  ...
}
```